# jQuery tooltip customize style using content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

I need to customize my tooltip to look something like this:
[example](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style)

However, I am building it dynamically and need to add an image to the lookup with text so I am using the function "content". When I try to use this CSS in jsfiddle the arrow is messed up and it is adding an extra from to the image.

```
 $(function () {
  $(document).tooltip({
      items: ".link",
      tooltipClass: "arrow",

      content: function () {


          var $this = $(this),
              random, html = "";
          var frame = "<div class='arrow1'>";
          var lowertext = "<div class ='tooltiptext'>Learn More</div>"
          var image = "<img class='webimage' src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ER0wkPWykNE/default.jpg'/>"
          return frame + image + lowertext + "</div>";

      }
  });
});
```

Please see my jsfiddle here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su8eK/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su8eK/2/)

Basically, I changed the following style rules to remove 2 of the borders from your arrow, changed the z-index so the content in the tool tip is always on top, and removed overflow:hidden from your arrow class so the arrow could be displayed.  So these rules:

```
  .arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: -15px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    tranform: rotate(45deg);
    border-bottom:none;
    border-right:none;
    z-index:-1;
  }

  .arrow {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    bottom: -16px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks great!Any way to have the arrow on the bottom and wrap the entire tooltip to the image?Thx for your time!

Comment: @user1163234  http://jsfiddle.net/Su8eK/4/  remove width property of the wrap, and add position property in tooltip js.  also change releveant border css rules for arrow.  had to write some css for the hello text to move it down for demonstration.